# How to matrix power function in Rcpp?

Tags: rcpp

Is there a way to raise a matrix to a power of 0.5 in Rcpp or RcppArmadillo? I don't want the element-wise power because I know that can be done by using pow function.

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking about a function `expm()`, I am using one by wrapping around the code from the namesake CRAN package [expm](http://cran.rstudio.com/package=expm) in my (incomplete) [RcppKalman package on GitHub](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppkalman):

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

/* Interface to expm package. */
typedef enum { Ward_2, Ward_1, Ward_buggy_octave } precond_type;

/* Matrix exponential exp(x), where x is an (n x n) matrix. Result z
 * is an (n x n) matrix. Mostly lifted from the core of function
 * expm() of package Matrix, which is itself based on the function of
 * the same name in Octave. */
void (*expmat)(double *x, int n, double *z, precond_type precond_kind);

extern "C" void R_init_RcppKalman(DllInfo *dll) { 
    expmat = (void (*) (double*, int, 
                        double*, precond_type)) R_GetCCallable("expm", "expm"); 
} 

//' This function computes the exponential of a matrix.
//' 
//' This functions calls the \code{expm} function from the eponymous package 
//' \pkg{expm}. This is implemented via a registered function call, and does
//' not required explicit linking at the C level. However, the \pkg{expm} package
//' is imported in order to access its registered function at the C level.
//' [...]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat expm(arma::mat x) {
    arma::mat z(x.n_rows, x.n_cols);
    (*expmat)(x.begin(), x.n_rows, z.begin(), Ward_2);
    return z;
}
```

Some of the strange-looking stuff in the file is just the mechanics of getting `expm` from that package.  The `arma::mat expm(arma::mat x)` function is pretty regular (and I guess I should make it `const &` as well).

*Edit:* Re-reading your question, I think I misunderstood. You were not asking for the matrix exponential.  But then .... what exactly is it your are asking for if it is not element-wise?